# "module 'folium.features' has no attribute 'CircleMarker' "

Tags: python, folium

I would like to use circlemarker to show geomap on my project.
Here is what I wrote:

```
states = folium.map.FeatureGroup()
i=0
for lat, lng, in zip(dataframe_filtered.location_latitude, dataframe_filtered.location_longitude):
    states.add_child(
        folium.features.CircleMarker(
            [lat, lng],
            radius=5, # define how big you want the circle markers to be
            color='yellow',
            fill=True,
            fill_color='blue',
            fill_opacity=0.6,
        )
    )
    i+=1
```

However, I am getting an error:

> "module 'folium.features' has no attribute 'CircleMarker' "

Comment: try `folium.CircleMarker` and if it does not work then please update the version of folium that you are using

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
folium.features.CircleMarker
```

to

```
folium.CircleMarker
```

I guess the new `folium.features` has removed the `.CircleMarker` option.
Just call `.CircleMaker` directly from `folium` should be fine.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that this is caused due to use of a old release of folium. Try updating your module download and letting us know if it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try `pip install --upgrade folium`